# Why are the eigen vectors not calculated as expected for cube-like point clouds with the Eigen library?

Tags: c++, vector, eigen, point-cloud-library, eigenvector

For a project using 3d cameras, I want to calculate the oriented bounding box of a point cloud.
I am using [this algorithm](https://codextechnicanum.blogspot.com/2015/04/find-minimum-oriented-bounding-box-of.html).
For general cuboids it worked well, but when testing the algorithm with a cube, the bounding box was oriented the wrong way.

I have set up a small demo project only using Point Cloud Library and Eigen like this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
    
// Perfect Cube - Works
cloud.points.push_back({ 10, 11, 11 });
cloud.points.push_back({ 10, 11, 10 });
cloud.points.push_back({ 10, 10, 11 });
cloud.points.push_back({ 10, 10, 10 });
cloud.points.push_back({ 11, 11, 11 });
cloud.points.push_back({ 11, 11, 10 });
cloud.points.push_back({ 11, 10, 11 });
cloud.points.push_back({ 11, 10, 10 });

// Calculate Centoid
Eigen::Vector4f centroid{};
pcl::compute3DCentroid(cloud, centroid);

Eigen::Matrix3f covariance{};
pcl::computeCovarianceMatrixNormalized(cloud, centroid, covariance);

std::cout << "Covariance:" << std::endl;
std::cout << covariance << std::endl;

const Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3f> solver{ covariance, Eigen::ComputeEigenvectors };
Eigen::Matrix3f eigen_vectors = solver.eigenvectors();
   
std::cout << "Eigen Vectors:" << std::endl;
std::cout << eigen_vectors << std::endl;
```

When adding a perfect cube to the point cloud like in the example, the algorithm works well, we get eigen vectors that are perfectly aligned to the edges of the cube `((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1))`. If we just change the cube a little bit (e.g. changing just the first value to 10.05), the eigen vectors are not longer aligned to the edges at all `((-0.883215, 0, -0.468968), (0.33161, 0.707107, -0.624527), (0.33161, -0.707107, -0.624527))`, although the covariance matrix only changes very little. The misalignment also happens with cubes that have more than just eight points.

Do I have a mistake in my thinking here?  How can I get the orientation of a cube point cloud? For other cuboids, the algorithm and eigen vector calculation works very well. I have not yet found any solution for this problem anywhere else.

Thank you for your help!

Tobi

Comment: Your eigenvalues are very close to each other, which means that small changes can have a lot influence on the eigenvectors. For the perfectly aligned cube actually any orthonormal set of vectors would be valid. The disturbance of `0.05` is relatively large compared with the precision of `double`, so it significantly fixes at least one Eigenvector into a different direction).

Comment: @chtz Thank you for your answer. As you say the disturbance is relatively large, do you have a clue on how to reduce it? As I think an absolute disturbance of e.g. `0.05m` is not that high compared to a cube with edge length `1m`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think your expectation that you have to get the unit vectors for your undisturbed cube is wrong (it happens to be what Eigen returns, when the eigenvectors could be arbitrary). Compare the covariance of an axis aligned cube to that of any rotated cube (with equal side length) and then try to explain how an Eigendecomposition should be able to determine the orientation from that.

Comment: The covariance matrix for a box is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix. This means that **all** vectors are eigenvectors (not just the 3 vectors that Eigen returns). So this is not a programming problem but a math one.

Comment: I am unsure what your actual goal is here. If you want to find out position and orientation of a box/cuboid in a point cloud (measured by a 3d camera), I would rather try to fit planes with RANSAC (up to 3 planes, partially with angle/axis constraints)

Comment: Okay, maybe I understood the whole system of covariance and eigen values wrong, as I only had to do with them for using the mentioned bounding box algorithm. I thought that the covariance would give you the directions of the distribution of the points, and applying eigen decomposition would return the appropriate direction vectors. When creating a rotated cube, i got a similar covariance matrix and eigen vectors. I think what confused me the most was that the algo works well for non-cube cuboid point clouds. I didn't know that you can get the orientation from RANSAC, that sounds interesting.